# Proof of Compound Angle from Ptolemy's Theorem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-verification, circles, triangles

I have a query regarding a proof I'm reading on the additive Sine compound angle formula, which uses Ptolemy's theorem.

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sine_cosine.shtml

I'm looking at the additive Sine section. The line BC is defined to be the diameter of the circle and is of length 1. All the sides except AD are obvious through basic trigonometry as the angle BAC=BDC=90 degrees. The final line is the application of Ptolemy's theorem.

However, I do not understand how they have arrived at the fact $AD = sin(\alpha + \beta)$. Can someone shed some light on how this is the case?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: By just reading through the proof: "The Law of Sines supplies the length of the remaining diagonal.". So just do that: go back to formula (3) in the paper and note that $\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{AD}=2R=BC=1$, which is exactly the statement you were looking for

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble seeing this. How do you equate $\frac{sin(\alpha + \beta)}{AD}$ and $2R$? I thought the Law of Sines only applied to sides and angles of the same triangle. I don't see how to apply the Law of Sines there when $BC$ and $AD$ can't be sides of the same triangle.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now, I'd overlooked the implications of (3) when reading the proof, stupid. Thanks, if you submit that as an answer I'll make the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just reading through the proof:

> "The Law of Sines supplies the length of the remaining diagonal."

So just do that: go back to formula $(3)$ in the paper and note that

$$\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{AD}=2R=BC=1,$$

which is exactly the statement you were looking for